# Member List / Auto Correct in Visual Studio 2019 C++ strange default behavior

Tags: c++, autocomplete, visual-studio-2019

The following **'Auto Correct' issue** occurs when typing e.g. `std::cout <<`.

After typing `std::cout` and a space this automatically gets corrected to `std::count`, which is the best match in the list.

**I cannot find any setting to disable this 'feature'.**

**Update:** Researching further, I find

1. Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->Intellisense->*Member List Filter Mode* is the relevant setting. Default is "Fuzzy" and this makes `count` a match for `cout`. Setting to "Smart" removes this match.
2. Still I wonder why pressing Space "commits the member list". There are settings for chars which commit, but Space is not mentioned. I would be fine with Tab, but **if I just type things (with spaces) I don't want any messing about.**
3. I like the "fuzzy" matching in principle to get an overview, but I hate the auto-commit.

[image: example]

Comment: Why is including the header a problem?

Comment: It should adjust your code if you say so (pressing tab or enter for example). Which version of Visual Studio do you have installed?

Comment: @chris including the header removes the problem, because the correct match (aka std::cout) is found and no correction takes place. Bernd: Latest version 16.7. updated yesterday, the feature was also there in the previous 16.6.x.

Comment: Right, what I'm asking is why simply going and adding the include isn't a workable solution to this problem (since you mentioned it in the question, it's presumably not a good enough solution).

Comment: I just want to avoid auto-corrections in general, since they can go wrong as my example shows. Why am I unable to find any documentation of this feature? Stop focusing on the include, please.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant setting is this one found in *Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->Intellisense*

[image]

very aptly named - as per usual! *The funny part is that the 'Aggressive Member List' is way less aggressive wrt. auto-correcting*

**Setting this to `True` leads to the desired effect:
Only `Tab` 'commits', i.e. inserts the (possibly inadvertently) selected member.** **Typing is not affected otherwise!**

link of interest: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/415157/not-possible-to-disable-c-autocomplete.html